# Angular 15 Services Issue with Sharing Data between components

Tags: angular

I have issue with Services in Angular 15 sharing data between components

here are the files

**sample.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleService {
    userName!: string;
    constructor(){
        console.log('SampleService Object created!')
    }

    updateUserInfo(userName: string){
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    getUserName(){
        return this.userName;
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Comp1Component } from './comp1/comp1.component';
import { Comp2Component } from './comp2/comp2.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Comp1Component,
    Comp2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**comp1.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SampleService } from '../services/sample.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp1',
  templateUrl: './comp1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp1.component.css'],
  providers: [],
})
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit{

  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sampleService.updateUserInfo('John Doe');
    console.log('User Name is - '+this.sampleService.getUserName());
  }


}
```

**comp2.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SampleService } from '../services/sample.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp2',
  templateUrl: './comp2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp2.component.css'],
  providers: [],
})
export class Comp2Component implements OnInit{
  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('User Name is - '+this.sampleService.getUserName());
  }

}
```

When I am running, I see in console every time new object is getting created for "SampleService"

Expected to see only once as it is Singleton Service.

Anything wrong I am doing here?

One Object across the app for this Service

Comment: Show how the two components are placed (parent). I have tried it. It works great with Angular 15. And the code you show looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell angular engine that it is a provider to do that see below.

Import `SampleService` in `app.module.ts` and add in under provider:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Comp1Component } from './comp1/comp1.component';
import { Comp2Component } from './comp2/comp2.component';
// import sampleservice here
Import {SampleService} from './sample.service.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Comp1Component,
    Comp2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [SampleService], // reference it here
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```